# Move each of edge loop's vertices by their relative weights in a vertex group

Tags: transforms, vertex-groups

So, I have an edge loop weightpainted and I want to move that edge loop's vertices by their relative weights, How can I do that?

[image: Edge Loop]

[image]

I skimmed through the blender's official documentation and I found a solution, maybe there is another one and you're welcome to post it!

So the way I did it is by using the lattice modifier, someone wondering and not knowing a way to do it might find it useful

1. Add and scale a lattice however you like, I scaled it enough to contain the mesh (Object Mode):
2. Add lattice modifier to the mesh you're trying to transform
3. Input recently created **lattice** as an object in the modifier's object field and the vertex group you're trying to transform in the vertex group field.
4. Then select the **lattice** and switch to edit mode, transform the lattice and the vertex group will transform according to the lattice.

*My reputation here doesn't allow more than to links, I'd love to be more illustative by the help of images.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you can use any of the *deform* modifiers to do this, and while a lattice can be deformed in many ways (and so your VG), even a hook modifier to a simple empty will do, eg:

[image]

to get this:

[image]